# F# inner join alternative query does not work (sample from Expert F# 4.0)

Tags: f#

```
open System
open FSharp.Linq
open FSharp.Data.TypeProviders
type NorthwindDb =
    SqlDataConnection<"Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=SSPI;">

let db = NorthwindDb.GetDataContext()
db.DataContext.Log <- System.Console.Out
```

I am following along Expert F# 4.0 Chapter 13 on queries. According to the book, an inner join query like this:

```
let innerJoinQuery =
    query {
        for c in db.Categories do
        join p in db.Products on (c.CategoryID =? p.CategoryID)
        select (p.ProductName, c.CategoryName)
    }
    |> Seq.toList
```

can be replaced with

```
let innerJoinAlternative =
    query {
        for p in db.Products do
        select (p.ProductName, p.Category.CategoryName)
    }
    |> Seq.toList
```

I get the following error:

```
error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'Category' is not defined
```

Note: Northwind database schema is [here](https://northwinddatabase.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Assume that most people don't have the book on their table.  What is `db`? An Entity Frameworkd context? A SqlDataProvider? Something else? With EF, you have to define your entities and properties before you can use them.

Comment: Assuming db is an Entity framework context, you would need a foreign key connecting the Categories table to the Products table.  Without this key, Entity Framework cannot automatically provide a Category property for the Product type.

Comment: Unfortunately, the book did not mention Entity Framework.